# VB.Net - LDAP: The size limit was exceeded

Tags: vb.net, ssis, active-directory, directory, ldap

I'm using a script that should pull right at 1400 records from our LDAP ( i double checked by running the same filter in Apache Directory Studio and the query ran successfully).  The output will be used as a SSIS SQL source.  I know our page limit on the LDAP is set at 2000 however every time we run the script below we get the following error message "The size limit was exceeded".  Can anyone see what can be modified in our script to overcome this error message?  I've tried setting "request.SizeLimit = Integer.MaxValue" and have tried  "request.SizeLimit = 2000" just after however the same error message of "The size limit was exceeded" persists.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports System.DirectoryServices.Protocols
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute()> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits UserComponent

Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()

    'Set ldap server string and port number that will be bound against
    Dim con As New LdapConnection(New LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ldap.company.com:636"))

    'Set the username and password of the service account used to bind against ldap.company.com
    Dim credential As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")

    'Enable SSL ring bind to ldap.company.com
    con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = True

    'Set authentication method used ring bind to ldap.company.com
    con.AuthType = AuthType.Basic

    'Pass along the credentials established earlier
    con.Credential = credential

    Using con

        'Set what attributes to pull from ldap.company.com
        Dim attributesToReturn As String() = New String() {"uid", "companyID", "givenName", "Nickname", "MiddleName1", "sn", "generationQualifier", "Degree", "displayName", "mail", "PSCareerC1", "PSCareerDescC1", "PSProgC1", "PSExpTermC1", "Affiliation", "PrimaryAffiliation", "PrincipalName", "telephoneNumber", "OrgUnit", "title"}

        'Set the search scope and filter for the query against ldap.company.com
        Dim request As New SearchRequest("OU=people,DC=company,DC=com", "(objectClass=person)", SearchScope.Subtree, attributesToReturn)

        Dim response As SearchResponse = DirectCast(con.SendRequest(request, New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), SearchResponse)

        'Send ldap bind request to ldap.company.com using the paramaters set above
        con.Bind()

        If response.Entries.Count > 0 Then

            Dim counter As Integer = 0

            'Enumerate through each entry, pulling each of the attributes requested
            For Each entry As SearchResultEntry In response.Entries

                OutputBuffer.AddRow()

                Dim Affiliations(5) As String
                Dim Title(5) As String

                OutputBuffer.DN = entry.DistinguishedName.ToString()

                Dim attributes As SearchResultAttributeCollection = entry.Attributes
                For Each attribute As DirectoryAttribute In attributes.Values

                    For i As Integer = 0 To attribute.Count - 1
                        If TypeOf attribute(i) Is String Then

                            If attribute.Name = "uid" Then

                                'Set NetID to the uid attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.NetID = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "givenName" Then

                                'Set FirstName to the givenName attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.FirstName = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "Nickname" Then

                                'Set Nickname to the Nickname attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.Nickname = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "MiddleName1" Then

                                'Set MiddleName to the MiddleName1 attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.MiddleName = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "sn" Then

                                'Set LastName to the sn attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.LastName = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "generationQualifier" Then

                                'Set Suffix to the generationQualifier attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.Suffix = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "Degree" Then

                                'Set Degree to the Degree attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.Degree = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "displayName" Then

                                'Set DisplayName to the displayName attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.DisplayName = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "companyID" Then

                                'Set UniqueID to the companyID attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.UniqueID = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "mail" Then

                                'Set Email to the mail attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.Email = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "title" Then

                                OutputBuffer.Title = attribute(i).ToString()

                                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title(0)) Then
                                    Title(0) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Title = Title(0)
                                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title(1)) Then
                                    Title(1) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Title = Title(0) + ", " + Title(1)
                                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title(2)) Then
                                    Title(2) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Title = Title(0) + ", " + Title(1) + ", " + Title(2)
                                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title(3)) Then
                                    Title(3) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Title = Title(0) + ", " + Title(1) + ", " + Title(2) + ", " + Title(3)
                                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title(4)) Then
                                    Title(4) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Title = Title(0) + ", " + Title(1) + ", " + Title(2) + ", " + Title(3) + ", " + Title(4)
                                End If

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "telephoneNumber" Then

                                'Set Telephone to the telephoneNumber attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.Telephone = attribute(i).ToString()


                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "PSCareerC1" Then

                                'Set PSCareerC1 to the PSCareerC1 attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.PSCareerC1 = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "PSCareerDescC1" Then

                                'Set PSCareerDescC1 to the PSCareerDescC1 attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.PSCareerDescC1 = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "PSProgC1" Then

                                'Set PSProgC1 to the PSProgC1 attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.PSProgC1 = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "PSExpTermC1" Then

                                'Set PSExpTermC1 to the PSExpTermC1 attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.PSExpTermC1 = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "PrimaryAffiliation" Then

                                'Set PrimaryAffiliation to the PrimaryAffiliation attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.PrimaryAffiliation = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "PrincipalName" Then

                                'Set PrincipalName to the PrincipalName attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.PrincipalName = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "OrgUnit" Then

                                'Set OrgUnit to the OrgUnit attribute value from ldap.company.com
                                OutputBuffer.OrgUnit = attribute(i).ToString()

                            ElseIf attribute.Name = "Affiliation" Then

                                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Affiliations(0)) Then
                                    Affiliations(0) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Affiliations = Affiliations(0)
                                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Affiliations(1)) Then
                                    Affiliations(1) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Affiliations = Affiliations(0) + ", " + Affiliations(1)
                                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Affiliations(2)) Then
                                    Affiliations(2) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Affiliations = Affiliations(0) + ", " + Affiliations(1) + ", " + Affiliations(2)
                                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Affiliations(3)) Then
                                    Affiliations(3) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Affiliations = Affiliations(0) + ", " + Affiliations(1) + ", " + Affiliations(2) + ", " + Affiliations(3)
                                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Affiliations(4)) Then
                                    Affiliations(4) = attribute(i).ToString()
                                    OutputBuffer.Affiliations = Affiliations(0) + ", " + Affiliations(1) + ", " + Affiliations(2) + ", " + Affiliations(3) + ", " + Affiliations(4)
                                End If

                            End If
                        End If
                    Next

                Next
                counter = counter + 1
            Next
        End If
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: When the LDAP client sets the size-limit in the search request, that value cannot be greater than the server's size limit. If the server has a size-limit of 1000, setting the *client requested* size-limit will not override the 1000.

Comment: Thanks, we've verified that the SizeLimit on the server is set to 2000, and the results of the filter used return about 1400 users when run via Apache Directory Studio.  I agree that the PagedSearch is probably what will be needed, do you have any examples of that for VB.net?  I can only seem to find examples in C#.

Answer (score -1):

The error says that "The size limit was exceeded".

- It could be that someone have changed your AD:s MaxPageSize
- It could be that you use diffrent accounts with diffrent acces to OU:s
- It could be that MaxPageSize = 1000. And when you do your Apachesearch perhaps the browser have paging (most likely)

Either way the error says to You that You have to use Paged search.
You can google and find out how to.

A sidenote: In AD its better to use ObjectCategory in the filter beacuse it is indexed:

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
```